# How do I import bootstrap-sass once and use it in several files?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

In the docs you can read the following:

*Import Bootstrap into a Sass file (for example, application.css.scss) to get all of Bootstrap's styles, mixins and variables!*

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

I have several scss files. One for every major section of my app (user-page.scss, admin.scsss etc).

I tried making one application.scss and imported bootstrap as in the docs. I added the file in index.html after bootstrap.scss and before all my other scss files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-compass.scss" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/application.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/intro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/admmin.css">
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/scss --no-cache --update intro.scss:intro.css
      error intro.scss (Line 22: Undefined mixin 'make-row'.)
```

So it seems it does not find bootstrap. It works if I import bootstrap in each file. Is this the right apporach? I think not. I get problem when I try to manually override a bootstrap variable.

How can I have several scss files and only import bootstrap once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think you're mixing SCSS import with HTML CSS links. So this bit here is wrong:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-compass.scss" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/application.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/intro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/admmin.css">
```

I assume this is from your built HTML file. Your HTML does not know what an SCSS file is. Your SCSS must be processed into a CSS file before it is usable in your final HTML file.

The way to import an SCSS file is to use that import command **inside the parent SCSS file** at the top. So if your main SCSS file is `application.scss`, then at the top of that, you import your other SCSS files:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

But you need to make sure that the `_bootstrap.scss` file is in the same directory as your `application.scss` file for this import to work.

Comment: Gah, of course this is the way it should be. Works very good. Thank you.